# Mercurial: repository layout for multi-customer project

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging, repository-design

We have this webapp product being deployed for multiple customers and think about switching from svn to mercurial. In svn, we see the trunk as our projects 'core', while branches are setup for each customer.

Now I wonder what the best repo layout might be in mercurial.

Lets say the project basically is made out of three main folders: `html`, `css`, `js`.

While the contents of `/html` stay the same across customers, we have customizations in `/css` & `/js`.
Right now these customizations live in separate files, such as `skin.css`, so we can clearly tell the real on-purpose-customizations from fixes/changes to the core/common files.

SVN then lets us partially commit changes from customer branches back to the trunk, so we can fix global stuff while working on customer projects. As I understand, partial commits are not supported in mercurial right now.

So, how do we best approach this situation in mercurial? 
Should we have one central core repo(possibly with release branches) and clone customer projects as separate (remote) repos?
Is it better to have all - core & customer branches - inside one repo?

Thanks a lot for any pointer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would split the project to two repos: core (html) and customer (css, js). "core" is easy to understand. For "customer", I would start with a generic or fallback set of styles. Then make a clone off the generic styles for each customer. To make a build for one customer, you need to pull from both core and that customer clone. This way different customers are isolated but still know about each other through the generic style. So if there's any style you want to change cross all customers, you just need to commit to the generic styles and let each customer clone pull. I wouldn't make different customers totally different repos.

The problem with having one single repo is whenever you make a clone for one customer, you carry around an irrelevant part (html). And unexpected modifications can be easily leaked into html. For the same reason, your project should probably have been split to two projects even in SVN.

Comment: By saying pull from core & customer, do you mean having them setup as subrepositories of per-customer-repos?

Comment: @Carsten, whenever you make a build for customer A, you need two parts - the core (html) and the style for A. It's up to you how to set them up though. I don't know exactly what you mean by "subrepositories of per-customer-repos"

Comment: sorry, I was a bit unclear. 
If I get you right, 'customer A' might also be a branch of the repo 'customers', for example.
Now, how would you treat the core repo? Would you have a Mecurial subrepo in the customers repo that checks out 'core'? 
Or would you 'just' pull core files into the customers working copy?

Comment: @Carsten, either ways seem fine to me. It depends which one is more important to you - making pulling from core easily and automatic, or making a clean isolation between customer and core.

Comment: @Kay: imho subrepos would fit better since you can specify concrete revisions across, using just a pull from time to time would maybe a bit harder to follow.  

Thanks for your feedback, helped settling this!